# separate results by username login`s in JSP

Tags: jsp, authentication

[image: This table is the one that I want to display][image: This is Clients (System users) table]how can I separate database content according to which user is logged in, so that each users could see only his content. I am Not sure if you need actual tables from MySql, if you do, i will edit them.

Login

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" import="java.text.*" errorPage="" %>
<%

Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","root",         "root");

ResultSet rsLoginFunction = null;
PreparedStatement psLoginFunction=null;

String sUserID=request.getParameter("username");
String sPassword=request.getParameter("password");
String message="User login successfully ";

try{
String sql ="Select * from clients where username=? and password=?";

psLoginFunction=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
psLoginFunction.setString(1,sUserID);
psLoginFunction.setString(2,sPassword);

rsLoginFunction=psLoginFunction.executeQuery();

if(rsLoginFunction.next())
{
  String username=rsLoginFunction.getString("Email")+"     "+rsLoginFunction.getString("clientID");

  session.setAttribute("Username",rsLoginFunction.getString("username"));
  session.setAttribute("Email",rsLoginFunction.getString("Email"));

 // session.setAttribute("iUserLevel",rsLoginFunction.getString("iUserLevel"));
 // session.setAttribute("sUserName",sUserName);

  response.sendRedirect("view_menu.jsp?error="+message);
}
else
{
  message="No user or password matched" ;
  response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp?error="+message);
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


/// close object and connection
try{
     if(psLoginFunction!=null){
         psLoginFunction.close();
     }
     if(rsLoginFunction!=null){
         rsLoginFunction.close();
     }

     if(conn!=null){
      conn.close();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
```

View, but not seperated

```
    <%@ include file="include/commonStrings.jsp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function del() {
    if (confirm("Do You Want to Delete this Menu?")) {
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/style.css" type="text/css"
charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<%
    menu_slno1 = request.getParameter("menu_slno");
    if (menu_slno1 != null)
        menu_slno = Integer.parseInt(menu_slno1);
    delete_menu = request.getParameter("delete_menu");


    if ("yes".equals(delete_menu)) {
        MenuId = request.getParameter("MenuId");
        x = stmt1
                .executeUpdate("Delete from menu where MenuId="
                        + MenuId);
    }
%>


<h2>VIEW MENUS</h2>

<table width="736" height="97" border="1">
    <%
        if (x == 1) {
    %>
    <tr bgcolor="#000000">
        <th height="35" colspan="9"><div align="center">
                Menu (<%=MenuId%>) deleted successfully
            </div></th>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <tr bgcolor="#089937">
                        </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <strong>MENU ID </strong>
            </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <strong>MENU NAME </strong>
            </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <strong>MENU INFO </strong>
            </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <strong>MENU PRICE </strong>
            </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <strong>MODIFY </strong>
            </div></td>
        <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
                <strong>DELETE</strong>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        int icount = 0;

//here i only know how to display whole table
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from menu");
        while (rs.next()) {
            //menu_slno = rs.getInt("menu_slno");
            MenuId = rs.getString("MenuId");
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><%=++icount%></div></td>

        <td><%=rs.getString("Name")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("Info")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getDouble("Price")%></td>

        <td><div align="center">
                <a href="edit_menu.jsp?MenuId=<%=MenuId%>">Edit</a>
            </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
                <a
                    href="view_menu.jsp?delete_menu=yes&MenuId=        <%=MenuId%>&MenuId=<%=MenuId%>"
                    onclick="return del()">Delete</a>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
<a href="add_menu.jsp">Add Menu</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: i`m in learning process, for this time let`s ignore this fact, but thank your for advice.

Comment: @user1703849 I have edited my answer, please let me know if I didn't get your question

Answer (score 0):

First create additional field in database called `role` which will store the permissions. Means if the user has Admin role he can access all contents, if not he will have some restrictions.

Then you can easily check it before showing output to user. Let me know if you need more help.

**Edit**

You can use following code: 
After adding third column in your table:

```
role=rsLoginFunction.getString("role")
if(role.equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
{
    //show the contents with full functionality.
    //like Delete, Edit, Add option
}
else
{
    //show the contents with limited access
    //like Allow user to only see the data, not allow him to modify
}
```

**Edit:**

You can do it using SQL query like:

```
select * from menu where login.username=menu.username
```

so it will show you records which are related to that particular user.

**Edit:**

```
String s = request.getParameter("username");
String query = "select * from menu where menu.username= s";
```

and then execute this query this will give you result as you want...

Comment: Hi, I am probably a bit late with response but anyway. I am noob in programming so i don't really know how to do that. I have 5 users that must be able to see only their content (4 columns out of 2 tables). My login can check wich user is logged in, but then i dont know how to display the columns they need (in  my second code that i have posted)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But I probably forgot to mention that all users have same level of access, but they must access different content (like only their own personal info) and this is what i don't know how to do.

Comment: can you post related database structure ?

Comment: I did. So below screenshot is Client (System user) table, and second one is the one i want to display. But I want each of users to be able to view and edit menu.name, menu.info and menu.price tables. Is it possible to verify user in one table (this is working) and then display results from other table?

Comment: No, the query does`t work, it says to check Sql syntax. You probably meant "select * from menu where CLIENT.username=menu.username", but it`s still not working.

Comment: i have edited the answer, let me know if you need anymore information